# image upload using url path on server

Tags: java

I am unable to upload image on the server using below code. 
getting exception :`can't read input stream with URL`

```
BufferedImage image = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.mkyong.com/image/mypic.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(url);

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("C:\\out.jpg"));
        ImageIO.write(image, "gif",new File("C:\\out.gif"));
        ImageIO.write(image, "png",new File("C:\\out.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You typically cannot write to `C:\\`. Use a different write location

Comment: Are you uploading an image or downloading it?

Comment: Your code is OK and i cannot see any error on it , so can you paste the printstacktrace() ?

Comment: Is your internet connection ok?

Comment: @Foolish I think so, he just asked here :P

Comment: getting exception 18:45:09,696 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!

18:45:09,696 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1275)